# Excel formula returns 0 instead of blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an Excel template and when I copy my formula down, it displays 0 instead of being blank. Any suggestions are appreciated. My formula is below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet2'!Y26),"",('Sheet2'!Y26))
```

Comment: What's the formatting applied to the cell?

Comment: Also check whether `ISBLANK('Sheet2'!Y26)` actually returns true.

Comment: it is formatted to currency

Comment: Nitesh, yes it does

Comment: This works great on my end. I'm using excel 2016 on windows. I would suggest refreshing your excel, and maybe checking for updates and doing a computer restart. The first couple times I tried it, a "0" came up, but then shortly disappeared, so I think it is just an excel error and not your formula. -Sorry I can't comment this, not 50 rep yet.

Comment: Try this: =IF(ISBLANK('Sheet2'!Y26),,('Sheet2'!Y26))

Comment: @MihailKuznesov that is going to leave 0 if condition is true

Comment: Mihail, still returning 0

Comment: @user7675421 show us a picture of your sheet ? I tried it and it works correctly for me

Comment: Luisrcher, how would a picture make a difference?

Comment: Because the behaviour is odd and with what you have given us, it is almost impossible for us to help you

Comment: The same formula works for you and it returns a blank instead of 0. Are you using excel 2016?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147954/discussion-between-luisarcher-and-user7675421).

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. As a workaround, try to Don't show zero in cell with 0. :) https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an option under `File|Options|Advanced|Display options for this worksheet`: Show a zero in cells that have zero value.

Simply uncheck that option and the zeros will vanish.

The downside is that this will unconditionally hide **all** 0 values (except where explicitly returned as a string), so it might not be a feasible solution for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning **zero** value to **('Sheet2'!Y26)** like following: `if(('Sheet2'!Y26)=0,"",('Sheet2'!Y26))` because u have formatted that cell as **currency**, get me back if it works!!